# Problem to create ViewPager programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm having the problem that I can not add a ViewPager (
Images Carousel) programmatically in my android app using Android Studio. So I built a simpler schema than my production app for testing, except that in this test I discovered that it only works at certain times.

Let's go to the code and explain what I wanted and what's going on.

**ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
    Context context;
    List<Bitmap> images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<Bitmap> images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item,container,false);

        ImageView image;
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        DisplayMetrics dis = new DisplayMetrics();
        image.setImageBitmap(images.get(position));
        container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

**viewpager_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Linear.java**

```
public class Linear extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linerar_activity);


        NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById (R.id.scrollView);
        scrollView.setFillViewport (true);
        ImageView imageView;
        List<Bitmap> bitmapList = new ArrayList<>();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play);
        bitmapList.add(bitmap);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play2);
        bitmapList.add(bitmap);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play3);
        bitmapList.add(bitmap);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play4);
        bitmapList.add(bitmap);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.play5);
        bitmapList.add(bitmap);

        LinearLayout ln = findViewById(R.id.ln);



        TextView tv = new TextView(Linear.this);
        tv.setText("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla\n" +
                "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla\n" +
                "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla\n" +
                "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla\n" +
                "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla\n" +
                "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla\n" +
                "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla\n" +
                "BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");
        ln.addView(tv);

        viewPager = new ViewPager(Linear.this);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(Linear.this,bitmapList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        imageView = new ImageView(Linear.this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //ln.addView(imageView);

        imageView = new ImageView(Linear.this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //ln.addView(imageView);

        ln.addView(viewPager);
        //ln.addView(tv);
        //ln.addView(imageView);



    }
}
```

**linerar_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

So what he really wanted to happen was:

Regardless of where it happened ln.addView (imageView) or ln.addView (tv) or ln.addView (viewPager) appeared in the order that was instantiated in LinearLayout.

What actually occurs:

The TextView and ImageView they can be instantiated as many times as they want, yet they will appear in the order in the scrollView Example:

```
ln.addView (imageView);
ln.addView (tv);
ln.addView (imageView);
ln.addView (tv);
```

the end product of this scrollView will be an image, a text, an image and finally a text.

The problem is when I give an ln.addView (viewPager) because it only appears when the scrollView content does not exceed the height of the device, Example:

1 - Only an ln.addView (viewPager): the viewPager will fill the entire screen of the mobile phone without the need to use the scrollView.

2 - Inserting some content + ln.addView (viewPager): in this example I'm using a textView that occupies 50% of the screen and the other 50% is occupied by viewPager, if the textView occupies 80% of the screen the viewPager would occupy 20 % of screen, if the screen was occupied 100% the scrollView would start working and the viewPager regardless of where it was instantiated it would not appear anymore.

**Summarizing the problem:**

That is, when the scrollView starts to work the viewPager will not work anymore.

Does anyone have any ideas for helping me?

Comment: Perhaps the ScrollView does recognize horizontal scroll actions, so the viewpager does not get the swipe event anymore?

Comment: When the viewer is instantiated and has space on the screen, the viewPager works with horizontal scrolling actions. The problem is when the vertical ScrollView grows more than the height of the screen, no matter where the viewPager is located, it does not show the first image of horizontal scrolling.